# Bluetooth socket only returns null. Android Bluetooth

Tags: android

Iam trying to connect to a socket by using the `connect` method. Iam generating a String containing the UUID like this:

```
MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("45341da0-c9c1-11e1-9b21-0800200c9a66");
```

Then constructing a `BluetoothSocket` like this:

```
BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
```

I also want to connect to a specific device by its mac-address:

```
BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice("00:1B:DC:0F:EC:7E");
```

and then making the `bluetoothSocket`

```
try {
    tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);    
    } catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception1: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Just for to test I added a breakpoint where the `tmp` object is been initialized inside the `try catch`. But it's only containing `NULL` The remote device does support OBEX OPP, but this is just a layer above the `RFCOMM` in the bluetooth stack, so I think my device should support RFCOMM for connections. Can anybody tell me why my `tmp` object is set to `null`?

Is there anyway I can test whenever the socket is created?

Comment: Have you tried using `tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( MY_UUID );` instead? I am actually doing a very similar application but my code seems to be nearly identical to yours.

Comment: When I do that, the phone only asks me to pair my device still after the pairing process has occured, so no thats not what am looking for. Thanks anyway. I only got the same exception when I try to do a connect: Service discovery failed.

Comment: Are you testing the application on a virtual device or on an actual device? Do you set your 'mmSocket' variable to tmp afterwards? tmp is initialized in the ConnectThread method, so once you leave it it will disappear.

Comment: I am testing on a real device. I am not using the ConnectThread from the bluetooth chat example, I know that I should put this in a thread. But this is just for test purposes, I will implement this functionality to a bigger app when this work properly..

Comment: OK, I'm not sure then...are you sure you have the correct UUID?

Comment: Thats the problem, I dont know the UUID of my external device. I can't program it, the sdptool under unix doesnt show up any UUID for this device..

Comment: Have you tried the default...`UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");`

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it. I think I should use the BluetoothServerSocket because my phone should act as a server..

Comment: Fair enough, sorry I couldn't help.